# SAML REQUEST FAILURE DOING CORRELATION

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, correlation, saml

Hi can any one help i am facing aissue while correlating the SAML REQUEST AND Relaystate values it is getting you are not authorized to the link can any one help me

Need to correlate the SAML REQUEest
Itried all the ways to pass but its failing

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue of authorization failure with SAML requests and RelayState values, ensure that the RelayState matches between the authentication request and SAML response. Verify and synchronize SAML configuration settings between the identity provider (IdP) and service provider (SP). Enable detailed logging on both sides to identify any errors or discrepancies in the SAML flow, and check for correct session state management. Validate the SAML request signature, review authorization rules, and consider network-related issues. Ensure up-to-date libraries and dependencies. If the problem persists, provide specific error details and consult documentation or community support for your SAML implementation for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing the response (at least partial) and knowing what values do you need to correlate so I can only suggest using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener which has different "Tester" modes where you can evaluate your regular/XPath/CSS/etc. expressions:

[image]

You can also use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) to see what variables are generated by your Post-Processors.

If you're looking for the "link" you can check out [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites-with-jm) but I cannot 100% guarantee that it will work for your particular setup, however you should be able to get the overall idea.